# Деактивация навыка Алиса на языке Python

Tags: python, яндекс-алиса

Пытаюсь правильно деактивировать навык, в документации говорится, что нужно правильно послать - "end_session": true. Для первого пробного навыка взял за основу предложенный пример из документации навыков, а именно развертывание на сервисе now и бот "купи слона".(https://github.com/yandex/alice-skills.git)

Текст в чат посылается путем запроса -

`res['response']['text'] = 'Текст'.`

Деактивацию навыка пытаюсь сделать так

```
 res['response']['text'] = 'Возвращайся'
    res['response']['end_session'] = True.
```

На вкладке "тестирование", после выполнения команды выше, я могу наблюдать в теле запроса -

```
 "response": {
    "end_session": true,
    "text": "Возвращайся скорее"
  }.
```

Т.е. насколько я понимаю, флаг был корректно установлен, но выхода из чата не наблюдается при тестировании на опубликованном навыке.

Что я делаю не так и каким образом можно сделать корректную деактивацию навыка.